Volume of space of atom in body-centered cubic unit: Wigner-Seitz Cell

There are actually two approaches here: Method 1: Utilize the symmetry of the crystal structure and obtain the result $a^3/2$. Method 2: Construct the Wigner-Seitz cell and calculate its volume. Just for the fun of it, I will calculate method two.
We have the following structure: Central atom at the co-ordinates $A_0 = (a/2, a/2, a/2)$ and the edge atoms at $A_1 = (0,0,0)$, $A_2=(0, 0,a)$, $A_3=(0,a,0)$, $A_4=(0,a,a)$, $A_5=(a,0,0)$, $A_6=(a,0,a)$, $A_7=(a,a,0)$ and $A_8=(a,a,a)$.
To construct the Wigner-Seitz cell, we need the normal vectors $\vec{n}_i = A_i - A_0$ and the midpoints $M_i = A_0 + \frac{1}{2}\vec{n}_i$. The following applies for $A_0$ and $A_1$:
$$\vec{n}_1 = A_1 - A_0 = -(a/2,a/2,a/2) = \frac{a}{2}(-1,-1,-1),$$
$$M_1 = A_0 + \frac{1}{2}\vec{n}_1 = (a/4,a/4,a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(1,1,1)$$
Similarly, the normal vectors $$\vec{n}_2 = \frac{a}{2}(-1,-1,1), \hspace{20pt} \vec{n}_3 = \frac{a}{2}(-1,1,-1), \hspace{20pt} \vec{n}_4 = \frac{a}{2}(-1,1,1), \hspace{20pt} ..., \hspace{20pt} \vec{n}_8 = \frac{a}{2}(1,1,1)$$ and the centers $$M_2 = \frac{a}{4}(1,1,3), \hspace{20pt} M_3 = \frac{a}{4}(1,3,1), \hspace{20pt} M_4 = \frac{a}{4}(1,3,3), \hspace{20pt} . ..., \hspace{20pt} M_8 = \frac{a}{4}(3,3,3)$$.
With the help of these midpoints, planes $E_i: \vec{n}_i(X-M_i)=0$ can be constructed. The following applies for $E_1$:
\begin{align} & E_1: \vec{n}_1 \cdot (X - M_1) = \frac{a}{2}(-1,-1,-1) \cdot (X - \frac{a}{4}(1,1,1)) = \frac{a}{2}(-x-y-z) + \frac{3a^2}{8} = 0 \\
& \Longrightarrow E_1: -x-y-z = -\frac{3a}{4}
\end{align}
Analogously you find:
\begin{align}
E_2: -x-y+z = \frac{a}{4}, \hspace{20pt} E_3: -x+y-z = \frac{a}{4}, \hspace{20pt} E_4: -x+y+z = \frac{5a}{4}, \hspace{20pt} ..., \hspace{20pt} E_8: x+y+z = \frac{9a}{4}
\end{align}
These planes intersect with the planes of the edge of the cube $$R_{1}: x = 0, \hspace{20pt} R_2: y=0, \hspace{20pt} R_3: z = 0, \hspace{20pt} R_4: x = a, \hspace{20pt} R_5: y = a, \hspace{20pt} R_6: z=a,$$
as well as with each other. The intersections of 3 planes are decisive for us in order to describe the Wiegner-Seitz cell. There are solutions for the following combinations:
\begin{align}
&P_1 = [R_1,E_1,E_2] = (0,a/4,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(0,1,2), \hspace{20pt} &P_2 = [R_1,E_1,E_3] = (0,a/2,a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(0,2,1), \\ &P_3 = [R_1,E_2,E_3] = (0,a/2,3a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(0,2,3), \hspace{20pt} &P_4 = [R_1,E_3,E_4] = (0,3a/4,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(0,3,2), \\
&P_5 = [R_2,E_1,E_2] = (a/4,0,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(1,0,2) , \hspace{20pt} &P_6 = [R_2,E_1,E_5] = (a/2,0,a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(2,0,1), \\
&P_7 = [R_2,E_2,E_6] = (a/2,0,3a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(2,0,3) , \hspace{20pt} &P_8 = [R_2,E_5,E_6] = (3a/4,0,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(3,0,2), \\
&P_9 = [R_3,E_1,E_3] = (a/4,a/2,0) = \frac{a}{4}(1,2,0), \hspace{20pt} &P_{10} = [R_3,E_1,E_5] = (a/2,a/4,0) =\frac{a}{4}(2,1,0), \\
&P_{11} = [R_3,E_3,E_7] = (a/2,3a/4,0) = \frac{a}{4}(2,3,0), \hspace{20pt} &P_{12} = [R_3,E_5,E_7] = (3a/4,a/2,0) = \frac{a}{4}(3,2,0) \\
&P_{13} = [R_4,E_5,E_6] = (a,a/4,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(4,1,2), \hspace{20pt} &P_{14} = [R_4,E_5,E_7] = (a,a/2,a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(4,2,1), \\ &P_{15} = [R_4,E_6,E_8] = (a,a/2,3a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(4,2,3), \hspace{20pt} &P_{16} = [R_4,E_7,E_8] = (a,3a/4,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(4,3,2), \\
&P_{17} = [R_5,E_3,E_4] = (a/4,a,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(1,4,2) , \hspace{20pt} &P_{18} = [R_5,E_3,E_7] = (a/2,a,a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(2,4,1), \\
&P_{19} = [R_5,E_4,E_8] = (a/2,a,3a/4) = \frac{a}{4}(2,4,3) , \hspace{20pt} &P_{20} = [R_5,E_7,E_8] = (3a/4,a,a/2) = \frac{a}{4}(3,4,2), \\
&P_{21} = [R_6,E_2,E_4] = (a/4,a/2,a) = \frac{a}{4}(1,2,4), \hspace{20pt} &P_{22} = [R_6,E_2,E_6] = (a/2,a/4,a) =\frac{a}{4}(2,1,4), \\
&P_{23} = [R_6,E_4,E_8] = (a/2,3a/4,a) = \frac{a}{4}(2,3,4), \hspace{20pt} &P_{24} = [R_6,E_6,E_8] = (3a/4,a/2,a) = \frac{a}{4}(3,2,4)
\end{align}

The Wiegner-Seitz cell can therefore be described with 8 equilateral hexagons and 6 squares with side length $l = \big|\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}\big| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}a$. If we connect the points $P_i$ with the atom $A_0$ in the middle, we get 8 pyramids with hexagonal bases and 6 with square bases, which together cover the volume of the Wiegner-Seitz cell.
The height of the square pyramids is $h_q = \frac{a}{2}$, while the height of the hexagonal pyramids is $h_h = \big|\overrightarrow{A_0M_1}\big| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a$. The volume is therefore:
\begin{align}
V=8V_h + 6 V_q &= 8 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}l^2h_h + 6 \cdot \frac{1}{3}l^2h_q \\
&= 8 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}a\right)^2\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a + 6 \cdot \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}a\right)^2\frac{a}{2}\\
&=\frac{a^3}{2}\end{align}

You missed a factor of $3$ in the numerator for the area of hexagon. The correct area is $(3\sqrt3/2) l^2$. You should get the correct answer now.

@Pranay You're right.
